# Using Java arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Please I need help with this, if I have an arraylist with elements [10,+,20,-,129]. I want to know how I can delete from behind the elements in the last index in the arraylist e.g removing 9 so that the array becomes [10,+,20,-,12]. Thanks

Comment: do you want to remove third digit in any item?

Comment: Is it an `ArrayList` of `String`?

Comment: Yes it is an arraylist of string

Comment: So if you repeat the operation, what is the expected behavior? `[10, +, 20, -, 129]` --> `[10, +, 20, -, 12]` --> `[10, +, 20, -, 1]` --> ???

Comment: I want to remove the last digit from the last item just  as a calculator's delete button works

Comment: If you figured out how to build that list in the first place, what exactly is the problem you are facing with doing this? Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its list of string elements, first take the last element and check whether the length of last element. If length is 1 then remove it, else trim one char from last.

```
// Adding element in list
list.add("1")
list.add("-");
list.add("23");
list.add("+");
list.add("123");
list.add("-");
// Size of List 
int size = list.size();
// Getting Last element
String  lastValue = list.get(size-1);
// check the length of last element
if(lastValue.length()<=1)
     list.remove(size - 1);
else
     list.set(size-1,lastValue.substring(0,lastValue.length()-1));
```

Hope it will solve the issue

```
Input : [1, -, 23, +, 123, -]
Output : [1, -, 23, +, 123]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12453582)

Answer (score 0):

Try get the item on the list, convert that item to string if it is not an array list of strings remove the digit you what by split or substring method then convert back to integer and add to the ArrayList.
example
 send your Array list to the generate new List

```
public ArrayList<String> globalStrings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    globalStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    globalStrings.add("10");
    globalStrings.add("+");
    globalStrings.add("-");
    globalStrings.add("129");

    //Before
    checklist(globalStrings);
    globalStrings = getNewStrings(globalStrings);
    //After
    checklist(globalStrings);


}
```

getNewStrings returns a new ArrayList string with the last index item deleted by one

```
 private ArrayList<String> getNewStrings(ArrayList<String> generateNew) {

    String getString = generateNew.get(generateNew.size() - 1);

    getString = getString.substring(0,(getString.length() - 1));

    generateNew.remove(generateNew.size() - 1);
    generateNew.add(getString);

    return generateNew;
}
```

To check the list, you can use the method below

```
private void checklist(ArrayList<String > check) {
    for(int count =0; count <check.size(); count ++) {
        Log.e("TAG", "List " + check.get(count));
    }
}
```

Comment: If the operation is repeated it should continue removing the last digit of the last item in the arraylist till the arraylist becomes empty

Comment: I just edited my post with codes example, try that to get your items deleted by one int.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may suites your needs:

```
String last = list.remove(list.size() - 1);
list.insert(last.substring(0,last.length() -1);
```

Disclaimer:
As I saw the diversity of the elements in your example I assumed the list is a list of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
List elements = Arrays.asList("10","+","20","-","144429");
String str = (String) elements.get(elements.size()-1);  //get value of last element
str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1); //get all characters besides last one
elements.set(elements.size()-1, str);   //replace last element in list
```

Comment: Code works fine for normal numbers, but not for operators like(+,-,\)

Comment: For single character elements you receives empty String element of list. You can add `if` statement to remove element from list if it consists of one character.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program to solve your problem.
You can add the null check conditions to make it better.

```
        List<String> a= new ArrayList<>();
    a.add("123");
    a.add("856");
    a.add("85");
    a.add("785");

    String trim = a.get(a.size()-1);
    trim = trim.substring(0,trim.length()-1);
   if(trim.equals("")){
       a.remove(a.size()-1);
   }
   else{
       a.set(a.size()-1,trim);
   }
    System.out.println(a);
```

output: [123, 856, 85, 78]

Comment: Code works fine for normal numbers, but not for operators like(+,-,\)

Comment: it will , you should have a arraylist of type string.

Comment: edited the answer to remove if it is blank entry after removing single chars like +,-

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this it may be work for you

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//add your data to this list
//suppose
// arrayList.add("10");
// arrayList.add("+");
// arrayList.add("20");
// arrayList.add("-");
// arrayList.add("129");
btnClick = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

 btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(arrayList.size() > 0) {
                String lastOne = arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1);
                String newOne = removeLastChar(lastOne);
                arrayList.remove(arrayList.size() - 1);
                if (!newOne.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    arrayList.add(arrayList.size(), newOne);
                }
                for (String item : arrayList) {
                    Log.d("TAG", item);

                }

            }
        }
    });
}
public String removeLastChar(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
}
```